# Unable to add data in the database using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

my controller class

```
 class BlistsController extends AppController{

    public $components = array('session');
    public function index(){
       $data = $this->Blist->find('all');
       $this->set('var_Blist', $data);
    }

    public function add(){
        print_r($this->request->data);

        if($this->request->is(array ('post', 'put'))){
            $this->Blist->create();
            if($this->Blist->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->session->setFlash("book added successfully");
                $this->reirect('index');
            }
            else{
                $this->session->setFlash("Unable to add book");
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

I used this code in my home pc. its working fine. but the same code is not working in my workplace. is there any enable need in the wamp.

when i print the `print_r($this->request->data)`
it shows

```
Array ( [Blist] => Array ( [F_bookId] => [F_name] => sadfasdf [F_author] => asdfasdf ) )
```

the field "F_bookId" is auto increment at the database table. 
Therefore it not showing at the display page.

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Blist Model
 *
 */
class Blist extends AppModel {

/**
 * Primary key field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $primaryKey = 'F_bookId';

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'F_name';

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'F_bookId' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'F_name' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'F_author' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Add.ctp

```
  <h1> Add Book Details </h1>
<?php
 echo $this->Form->create('Blist');
 echo $this->Form->input('F_bookId');
 echo $this->Form->input('F_name');
 echo $this->Form->input('F_author');
 echo $this->Form->end('Add Book');
?>
```

the final code which is working fine..

```
 public function add(){             

    $data = $this->request->data;//getting the values from the input fields

    //get the last record
    $lastRecordId = $this->Blist->find('first', array('order' =>array('F_bookId' => 'DESC')));

    //Split the book id, to generate a new book id
    $temp = str_split($lastRecordId['Blist']['F_bookId'], '4');        
    $data['Blist']['F_bookId'] = ($temp[0]. ((String)((int)$temp[1]+1)));

    if($this->request->is(array ('post', 'put'))){           
        $this->Blist->create();                        
        if($this->Blist->save($data)){
            $this->session->setFlash("book added successfully");
            $this->redirect('add');
        }
        else{
            debug($this->Blist->validationErrors);
            $this->session->setFlash("Unable to add book");
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get? what does the logging say? you have a typo in your code $this->reDirect('index') not related to your problem

Comment: no error showing bro... simply else block execution takes place and showing the msg unable to add book...

Comment: any validation errors? put in your else block: debug($this->Blist->validationErrors);

Comment: I assume you are using cakephp 2.*

Comment: yes i am using cakephp 2.5.4.

Comment: i used your code debug($this->Blist->validationErrors);  it say F_bookId not empty. but F_bookId field not displaying at the add.ctp thats because of Auto increment i think.... what should i do..

Comment: The problem is in your validation rules I think, could you show your validation rules in your Blists.php model?

Comment: i changed the reirect to redirect. i included the model class above.. kindly look into it

Answer (score 0):

Your id is auto-created by the auto increment feature of your database. There is no need to validate the user input for F_BookId since there is none and if you set the rule notEmpty on that field validation will trigger an error.

remove this part from your $validate array:

```
    'F_bookId' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
```

This should let your save your books.

On a sidenote: You might want to read about naming conventions concerning CakePHP to make your life easier: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Comment: thanks.. its working but primary key is empty... in the above file (add.ctp). the F_bookId field not displayed as a field in the add.ctp. F_bookId is a primary key, Varchar and not auto increment

Comment: Thanks a lot... its working... see the above new code

Comment: are you sure your database is setup ok? auto increment is on and value of the idea is not allowed null. Cause create() should create a new id